# The import javax.xml.rpc.encoding cannot be resolved

Tags: java, soap

I'm trying to run this code 
http://www.nactem.ac.uk/software/termine/webservice/termine_soap_client.java

and I get the following error: The import javax.xml.rpc.encoding cannot be resolved.

I'm using Oracle Java 7. What do I need to add to get this resolved?

Thanks,
Ivelina

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the relevant jars to your build path :
   *axis.jar, jaxrpc.jar and xerces.jar.*

Answer (score 7):

In case someone is using Maven, these are the only dependencies I needed in order to make wsdl2java goal work:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrpc-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
```